# c# unity ошибка при билде

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d, monodevelop

Когда запускаю проект в Unity - все работает. В MonoDevelop (режим отладки) - все работает. Но когда начинаю билдить проект - то вылетают ошибки:

> 1) Assets/Scripts/Shape.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `UnityEditor' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
>
> 2) Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

В самой юнити - запускаю и нормально играю, и нет никаких ошибок в ходе игры! Помогите плиз!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UnityEditor - это пространство имён редактора, т.е. все его классы существуют только в редакторе и не идут в билд. В итоге пока вы играете в редакторе - всё хорошо, когда пытаетесь собрать билд - это пространство имён отключается и выпадает ошибка.

У этой проблемы два возможных решения:

1. Переместить классы, которые используют это пространство имён в созданную папку с Editor. Дело в том, что все папки с именем "Editor", независимо от их положения в проекте не будут идти в билд.
2. Тот код, который использует классы из этого пространства имён поместить в дефайн.Код, находящийся внутри не будет попадать в билд и будет работать только пока вы находитесь в редакторе.

Код дефайна будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR

//ваш код

#endif
```

Comment: Оказалось не то заюзал что нужно )

Comment: Спасибо за уделённое время